# How to get consecutive numbers in an interrupted list?

Tags: support, markdown

How can i format my questions/answers so that i get consecutive numbers when a list is interrupted? All of my numbers start with 1 even if i set them manually to 1,2,3.

Have a look at my recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14476143/284240

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I always hit this.. And my work around is not to use the default list formatter. I manually number them instead.. Ugly

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: That's the problem. Above i've already numbered them manually. I even see this when i edit the answer. But as soon as i save it will be overridden with 1.

Comment: Ya I know.. My work around is to number them like this 1)... 2).... 3)....  Again ugly..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that. But you can avoid interrupting the list, by indenting everything that belongs to the item 4 spaces (that means code in there is indented 8 spaces!):

1. some stuff

   ```
   some code
   ```

   some more content related to item #1.
2. more stuff!

   ```
   neat code for the second item
   ```

   clarification about the code for #2.
3. the most **important** item

   This item is so important, that it contains

   ## A Heading

   and

   1. its own sublist
   2. with random
   3. stuff
4. a boring item, to demonstrate that even after a sublist the original list can continue.

Comment: Thanks, the 4 spaces helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476143/284240 Although it is sufficient in this case but might not always be what someone wants.